# Is map_metadata necessary for copying audio files with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata

Does it make a difference using `-map_metadata` for copying audio files with ffmpeg or can it be omitted because it is this the default already?

```
ffmpeg -i track.m4a -c copy -t 10 -map_metadata track-10s.m4a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use `-map_metadata` unless you don't like the default behavior, or if you need to do something special.

From the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

> By default (if you don't use `-map_metadata`), global metadata is
> copied from the first input file; per-stream and per-chapter metadata
> is copied along with streams/chapters. These default mappings are
> disabled by creating any mapping of the relevant type. A negative file
> index can be used to create a dummy mapping that just disables
> automatic copying.

If you want to use `-map_metadata` it requires an option to tell it what to do. You can't just use it alone by itself. Example: `-map_metadata 0:s:0` to copy metadata from the first stream of the input file to global metadata of the output file.